# Access rails development server from another computer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, server

I have a laptop installed with archlinux and an iMac. I want to do my rails development on the laptop which has no GUI, and to be able to look at the web app on the iMac. How do I access Phusion passenger server with my rails app that is running on the laptop from the iMac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `ifconfig` in a shell to get the IP address of your laptop in your internal network (look for something like `inet addr:192.168.1.104`). Make sure that your router doesn't block port 3000, and you should be able to access your app under that IP, e.g. `192.168.1.104:3000`.

Comment: Thanks Max, sorted! Had to use `ip addr` rather than `ifconfig`.